# Do something when event not set in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with my system.

```
$("#sf").on('keyup',function(){
  $("#daftarteman").html('<center><img src="../img/loader.gif" class="loader2"></center>');
  $.get('konten/daftarteman.php?q='+$("#sf").val(),function(daftarteman){
    $("#daftarteman").html(daftarteman);
  });
});
```

if the 'on keyup' is not set, do

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#daftarteman").load('konten/daftarteman.php');
},500);
```

but, if 'on keyup' is set, setInterval's script will not working (run according the 'on keyup' script)

Comment: What do you mean, *if the 'on keyup' is not set*? Do you want to check if there is not an event listener?

Comment: there is still an event listener. i mean for _if the 'on keyup' is not set?_ is, if no one do something where can active the event listener (on keyup)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, before running setInterval off the keyup event

```
$("#sf").off("keyup");
setInterval(function(){
  $("#daftarteman").load('konten/daftarteman.php');
},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the event has been registered on the element.

```
var elemEvents = jQuery._data( $('#sf')[0], "events" );
if(!elemEvents.hasOwnProperty("keyup")){
    //keyup event is not registered so execute setInterval
}
```

Use namespaced events if you are going to have multiple keyup handlers on "#sf"